# demo jax-rs resource not bound where expected on jboss

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jax-rs

im trying to whip up a small jax-rs demo.

i have this resource class:

```
@Path("/cart")
public class ShoppingCartResource {

    @EJB
    private ShoppingCartService shoppingCartService;

    @GET
    public String getCart() {
        ShoppingCart cart = shoppingCartService.getCart();
        return "cart with "+cart.getProducts().size()+" items";
    }
}
```

this class is packed inside a *.war called rest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war, itself inside an *.ear called ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear that i placed in the /deployments directory of jboss 7.1.3

my web.xml is empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
</web-app>
```

and my application.xml (in the ear) is auto-generated by maven:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
  <display-name>ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <ejb>services-impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>rest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/rest</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

when i start up jboss its picking up my war, as evident from the log:

```
09:52:19,392 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /rest
09:52:19,401 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"
```

but i cant hit this resource, no matter what url i try.
i've tried:

1. localhost:8080/rest/cart
2. localhost:8080/ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/rest/cart

and i keep getting 404.
where is the resource bound, or if its not really bound, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a legal (spec-compliant) way of deploying jax-rs resources without servlet/filter mapping, as described in the jax-rs docs [here](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.6.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e127) (the section says as7 but it actually applies to any Java EE 6 compliant AS).

the solution is to have an empty web.xml and then include an Application class annotated with `@ApplicationPath`:

```
@ApplicationPath("/root-path")
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JAX-RS applications need a configuration section in *web.xml* to properly set the servlet which manages rest calls.
Create a section in your *web.xml* like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseyRestService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>...</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JerseyRestService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The init parameter in the *servlet* section should include the packages containing the rest classes.
The *url-pattern* parameter can be changed to your preferred url prefix.

Comment: there's no implementation-agnostic way to do this? i dont really like the idea of depending on either jersey or resteasy

Comment: after some digging i found one - @ApplicationPath on your Application class + empty web.xml